# When I install a custom component, language is installed but jomla not detect

Tags: custom-component, language

That's the structure to a custom component.

[image: Archive list]

The installation is OK, but Joomla don't detect the languages that I have to that component.

That is the structure to my xml file.
[image: structure xml file]

Comment: Are the language files in the right language folder after the installation?